# Is the partial derivative allways zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, inverse-function

Assume that you have functions/parameters

$\theta,\phi,\mu,p_1,\ldots,p_n$

We have functions

$\theta(\mu,p_1,\ldots,p_N)=f(\mu)$

$\phi(\mu,p_1,\ldots,p_N)$.

Notice that the first function only depend on $\mu$.

We also have the functions

$\mu(\theta,\phi)=g(\theta)$

$p_1(\theta,\phi),\ldots,p_N(\theta_,\phi)$.

Notice that the first function only depends on $\theta$.

We assume that all the partial derivatives exist.

I am wondering if it can be shown that $\phi$ does not depend on $\mu$, or said another way that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mu}=0$?

Comment: What is preventing $\phi=\theta$ (in which case the claim implies $f'=0$)?

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks, good point, I will have to think more about this.

Comment: @Gae.S. If $\theta=\phi$, then $\mu(\theta,\phi)=g(\theta)=g(\phi)$. So the partial derivative with respect to $\phi$ is in one case zero, and in the other case $g'(\phi)$? I am sure I am missing something here, could you please  point out what I am missing?

Comment: The way I see it, if $\theta=\phi$, then $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mu}=\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial \mu}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu}=f'(\mu)$.